# Применение стилей к 2 и 3 элементам контейнера

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Не удается обратиться ко 2 и 3 элементам контейнера, чтобы сделать их невидимыми. `:nth-child()` не помогает. В HTML структуру не могу вмешиваться.

Как это можно решать по-другому? Желательно с помощью стилей.

CSS:

```
.main-product .product-holder:nth-child(2),
.main-product .product-holder:nth-child(3) {
    display: none;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="vc_row wpb_row vc_row-fluid main-product">
  <div class="vc_col-sm-12 wpb_column vc_column_container ">
    <div class="wpb_wrapper">
      <div data-columns="3" data-sidebar="no_sidebar" class="products-container   product-carousel view-grid">
        <div class="product-holder"></div>
      </div>
      <div data-columns="3" data-sidebar="no_sidebar" class="products-container   product-carousel view-grid">
        <div class="product-holder"></div>
      </div>
      <div data-columns="3" data-sidebar="no_sidebar" class="products-container   product-carousel view-grid">
        <div class="product-holder"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!--/ .products-container-->
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: *названичить* — опечатка?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Дело в том, что `product-holder` в этом примере всегда единственный элемент в его контейнере. Мне кажется, что хотите скрывать `.product-holder` внутри второго или третьего `.products-container`, вот так:

```css
.products-container:nth-child(2) .product-holder,
.products-container:nth-child(3) .product-holder {
  display: none;  
}
```

```html
<div class="vc_row wpb_row vc_row-fluid main-product">
  <div class="vc_col-sm-12 wpb_column vc_column_container ">
    <div class="wpb_wrapper">
      <div data-columns="3" data-sidebar="no_sidebar" class="products-container   product-carousel view-grid">
        <div class="product-holder">Первый</div>
      </div>
      <div data-columns="3" data-sidebar="no_sidebar" class="products-container   product-carousel view-grid">
        <div class="product-holder">Второй</div>
      </div>
      <div data-columns="3" data-sidebar="no_sidebar" class="products-container   product-carousel view-grid">
        <div class="product-holder">Третий</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: да, все верно - спасибо!